# Selenium webdriver : List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments `<WebElement>` type

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to store link in List, follow below code

```
public class frameswitch {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe");  
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    String baseUrl="https://www.udacity.com/";
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    String Title="Udacity - Free Online Courses and Nanodegree Programs";
    List<WebElement> linkElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    }
}
```

but facing error while using list

> The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments `<WebElement>` type

Comment: Did you import `java.util.List`? You may have accidentally imported `java.awt.List`, check your imports.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

The error says it all `The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <WebElement> type`. It means when you configured the `List` as in `List<WebElement> linkElements`, accidentally you have imported it from `java.awt.List` where it is not defined. Hence the error.

The following screenshot shows it all:

[image]

### Solution:

As a solution, I have used your own code importing `java.util.List` instead of `java.awt.List` and your code block works just fine:

```
package demo;

import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Q45402867_tagname_a {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");  
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        String baseUrl="https://www.udacity.com/";
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        String Title="Udacity - Free Online Courses and Nanodegree Programs";
        List<WebElement> linkElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        System.out.println(linkElements.size());
        for (WebElement ele:linkElements)
        System.out.println(ele);
    }

}
```

The output on the console is:

```
86
[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on ANY (ef81931f-9530-4998-8405-6581ab51c86e)] -> tag name: a]
...  84 more ...
[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on ANY (ef81931f-9530-4998-8405-6581ab51c86e)] -> tag name: a]
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: thanks and above code helps and now i can easily calculate links on any webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Check your import you have imported List from

```
java.awt.List
```

instead of

```
java.util.List
```