# The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <WebElement>

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I created a method called **public void campoRechamada** inside this method i tryed store a Datepicker inside a List , but the Eclipse show me the following message error:**The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments**

I do not know why the eclipse shows this message.

P.S.: I using Page Object.

Follow below my code and a print view of message error.

Class: **AcertoPerfilTratamentoOs**

```
public class AcertoPerfilTratamentoOs {

static WebDriver driver;

By cidade = By.id("cboCidade");
By tipoOcorrencia = By.id("txtTipoOcorrencia");
By telRes = By.id("txtTelResidencia");
By nomeCliente = By.id("txtCliente");
By campoVoip = By.id("txtVOIP");
By campoTelComercial = By.id("txtTelComercial");
By perfilUltimoAgendamento = By.id("txtPerfilPrimeiroAgOS");
By telCelular = By.id("txtTelCelular");
By codNet = By.id("txtCodNet");
By perfilUltimoAgend = By.id("txtPerfilUltimoAgOS");
By rechamada = By.id("txtDtRechamada");

public AcertoPerfilTratamentoOs(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}

public void camposCidade(String CampoCidade) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    WebElement elementCidade = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(cidade));

    Select slc = new Select(driver.findElement(cidade));
    slc.selectByVisibleText(CampoCidade);
}

public void campoTipoOcorrencia(String tipOcorrencia) {
    driver.findElement(tipoOcorrencia).sendKeys("reclamação");
}

public void campotelRes() {
    driver.findElement(telRes).sendKeys("2222-9999");
}

public void camponomeCliente() {
    driver.findElement(nomeCliente).sendKeys("Claudio");
}

public void campoVoip() {
    driver.findElement(campoVoip).sendKeys("5555");
}

public void campotelComercial() {
    driver.findElement(campoTelComercial).sendKeys("2222222");
}

public void campoultimoAgendamento() {
    driver.findElement(perfilUltimoAgendamento).sendKeys("segunda-feira");
}

public void campotelCelular() {
    driver.findElement(telCelular).sendKeys("99999-9999");
}
public void campoCodNet() {
    driver.findElement(codNet).sendKeys("123");
}
public void campoPerfilUltimoAgend() {
    driver.findElement(perfilUltimoAgend).sendKeys("Representante");
}
public void campoRechamada() {
    WebElement dateWidget = driver.findElement(rechamada);
    List <WebElement> columns = dateWidget.findElement(By.tagName("td")); 

}
```

}

Class: **ValidarEstrategiaAcertoPerfilLancamentoManualTest**

```
public class ValidarEstrategiaAcertoPerfilLancamentoManualTest {

static WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    SelecionarNavegador nav = new SelecionarNavegador();
    driver = nav.iniciarNavegador("chrome", "http://10.5.9.45/BkoMais_Selenium/");
}

@Test
public void logarAplicacao() {
    try {
        // Login Page
        LogarBkoMaisPage login = new LogarBkoMaisPage(driver);
        login.logar("844502", "Bcc201707");

        // Acessar a estratégia
        ProdutoNetEstrategiaAcertoDePerfilLancamentoManual AcertoPerfil = new ProdutoNetEstrategiaAcertoDePerfilLancamentoManual(
                driver);
        AcertoPerfil.AcessarEstrategia();

        // Registro Novo
        RegistroNovoCasoPage novoCaso = new RegistroNovoCasoPage(driver);
        novoCaso.registrarCaso();

        // Preenchendo o campo OCORRÊNCIA
        RandowNumber rn = new RandowNumber(driver);
        rn.randomNumber();

        // Preencher Campos da tela Tratamento Os
        AcertoPerfilTratamentoOs po = new AcertoPerfilTratamentoOs(driver);
        po.camposCidade(" ALMIRANTE TAMANDARE ");
        po.campoTipoOcorrencia("reclamação");
        po.campotelRes();
        po.camponomeCliente();
        po.campoVoip();
        po.campotelComercial();
        po.campoultimoAgendamento();
        po.campotelCelular();
        po.campoCodNet();
        po.campoPerfilUltimoAgend();
        po.campoRechamada();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Mensagem de erro: " + e);
    }
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(1200000);
    SairPagina sair = new SairPagina(driver);
    sair.sairBkoMais();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.quit();
}
```

}

[Eclipse Message Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69T23.jpg)

Comment: Did you import `java.util.List`?

Comment: Or is there some OTHER `List` class you're accidentally importing from somewhere?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45402867/selenium-webdriver-list-is-not-generic-it-cannot-be-parameterized-with-argume?rq=1

Comment: I imported import java.awt.List.

Comment: You used `findElement` instead of `findElements`

Comment: Thanks  Rafał Laskowski. After your answer the script It worked.

Comment: @LeandroPereira You're welcome! Happy coding!